# Google Analytics 'items' property not appearing in the dashboard for ecommerce events

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, react-native-firebase

I'm doing a Google Analytic integration to my react native application using the rnfirebase library (https://rnfirebase.io/). Below code snippets represent how I log the `add_to_cart` ecommerce event using the https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics#logAddToCart method.

```
    let addToCartObject = {
        'currency': 'USD',
        'items': [{
            'item_id': itemInfo.productId,
            'item_name': itemInfo.name,
            'item_category': this.state.selectedCategory.category.name,
            'item_variant': '[base]'
        }],
        'value': 33.75
    };
    analytics().logAddToCart(addToCartObject).then(() => {
        console.log(' ---------------- Logging add to cart success ------------- ');
    });
```

Even though the event logging happens without any error, I can only view the `currency` and `value` parameters for the `add_to_cart` events via the Firebase Analytic Dashboard. Parameter `items` is always missing. Anything I'm doing wrong here or something I've missed during the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In the object add the quantity parameter with the value added to cart.

Comment: I've tried adding `quantity` and  `item_quantity` at both item level and root level but the logging fails saying invalid parameter. Even the documentation (https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics/item) doesn't mention about a `quantity` parameter.